# How to hide the id passed in the route in react?

Tags: reactjs

How to hide the id from displaying in the url?

```
<Route path="/AddShop/:id" component = {AddShop} />
```

Comment: Just pass ID into redux state, and store it between page reloads in some persistent store, e.g. server initial state or JWT

Comment: Can you please give me one simple example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use state in your link

Route

```
<Route exact={true} path="/post_view" component={PostView} />
```

Link

```
<Link 
                to={{
                  pathname: `/post_view`,
                  state: {
                    id: item.id
                  }
                }}
                className="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right">
                view
            </Link>
```

View Page

```
const post_id = props.location.state.id;
```

The only constraint is when you share the link, the state wont have that id